# Column Matching Data featch in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @ompid NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(max)

SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ') as ' + Variable_Name + ' ,AVG(', 'AVG(') + Variable_Name
FROM charttest
WHERE ompid = 125

DECLARE @lastcol NVARCHAR(100) = (
        SELECT TOP 1 (Variable_Name)
        FROM charttest
        WHERE ompid = 125
        ORDER BY Variable_Name ASC
        )
DECLARE @Names2 NVARCHAR(500) = @Names + ') as ' + @lastcol + ''
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500)

SET @sql = 'SELECT  ' + @Names2 + ' FROM ompvaribles'

EXEC (@sql)
```

This is my sql query i had show second table avg but not getting second table records.

Comment: Before your EXEC command, can you add a "PRINT @sql" command, and let us know the exact SQL command which you're trying to run.  If's hard to help you without this information....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is actually not working with your query (I'm assuming you get an error), but in order to execute the dynamic query you've build you need to use:

```
exec sp_executesql @sql
```